# RMagick Compression with Cloudinary and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary, rmagick

I would like to use the RMagick Compression in Carrierwave before the image is uploaded to Cloudinary.

The local imagemagick tests showed that a 37MB File (Please don't ask why it has that size ;) ) was compressed to only 4,6 MB with an acceptable quality.

So now I would like to use the same functionality in my rails app with rmagick, but it seems like the preprocessing does not take place at all. The uploader uploads the original file with 37MB.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  process :compress => Magick::JPEGCompression

  def compress(compression_type)    
    manipulate! do |img|
      img = img.compression(compression_type)
    end     
    img     
  end
  ...
```

How can I achieve that the compression takes place and only the compressed file is uploaded to cloudinary?

Comment: Looking at some of the CarrierWave `process` examples, it looks like they all return the result of `manipulate!` directly, they don't return `img` at the end. Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try our [incoming transformation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_videos?query=inco&c_query=Incoming%20transformations#incoming_transformations).
For example, you can upload the image using [upload widget](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget) and add the incoming transformation in the upload preset. or use the SDK. For example:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("sample.jpg", 
  :width => 2000, :height => 1000, :crop => :limit, :quality => 70)
```